# Unzip Files Automatically

Tags: unzip

I'm looking for a free way to be able to unzip files automatically in a folder.  From what I've read, there seem to be a few ways to do this, but I'm limited because I do not have any zip/unzip software other than what is provided with Windows.  Additionally, I do want to incorporate the executable/task or whatever it might be into an SSIS package, as this is the only way I have to create a scheduled task in my environment.  Is this a tall order?  Any suggestions would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps as i also was looking for such a program as WinZip and WinRar are good but there are limitations and then i found **ExtractNow**

http://www.extractnow.com/